# IF/ELSE executes both blocks

Tags: batch-file

The following executes both the IF and the ELSE blocks

```
set sqlpackage_path=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe

if exist %sqlpackage_path% (
    echo %sqlpackage_path% exists
) else (
    echo %sqlpackage_path% does not exist
)
```

This is the result:

> C:\temp>set sqlpackage_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe
>
> C:\temp>if exist C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe (
>
> C:\temp>echo C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe exists C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe exists
>
> C:\temp>echo C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe does not exist C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe does not exist

When I try putting quotes around "%sqlpackage_path%" on the IF line, I get this message:

> \Microsoft was unexpected at this time

What is the right syntax for checking the existence of this file?

Answer (score 1):

Your environment variable evaluates to a string that contains parentheses. These are taken literally as part of the syntax. You need to enclose them in quotes, especially inside the if and else blocks:

```
set sqlpackage_path=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe

if exist "%sqlpackage_path%" (
    echo "%sqlpackage_path%" exists
) else (
    echo "%sqlpackage_path%" does not exist
)
```

If you need to avoid using quotes in the output from the `echo` command, use delayed expansion: add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the start of your file, and use `!sqlpackage_path!` instead of `"%sqlpackage_path%"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
set "sqlpackage_path=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe"

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ('set sqlpackage_path') DO IF /i "%%a"=="sqlpackage_path" (
 if exist "%%b" (
 echo %%b exists
 ) else (
 echo %%b does not exist
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Keeping the evaluation of the actual pathname until the very last possible moment.

The fundamental problem is that the `)` in the variable closes the if-true instruction.